# How to use symbolic links in Azure DevOps on Window (Visual Studio 2019 Team Explorer)

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, symlink, team-explorer

Imagine I have three team projects, one is a library and the other two use it:

1. C:\BaseLibrary
2. C:\ProjectOne
3. C:\ProjectTwo

Now imagine that I have a `tsconfig.json` in my base library, and I want to add symbolic links to it in the other two projects.

However, I run into this problem that Azure DevOps client which is called Team Explorer in Visual Studio 2019 doesn't understand it's a symbolic link, and on the next get latest version in another developer's machine, it copies a real copy to the hard that is not a link to the original file.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: How do you add the symbolic links to the Tsconfig.json file in the other two projects? would you mind sharing more details with me?

Comment: `mklink /H Link Target`. I'm creating both soft links and hard links using `/H` switch and it makes no difference.

Comment: Is the symbolic link obtained on another developer machine like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwfbf.png)?